# With Firemonkey, how to give feedback to the user ? (crHourglass)

Tags: delphi, feedback, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Usually, when I have a task which takes some time, I use a script like this:

```
procedure Work;
var
  cPrevious: TCursor;
begin
  cPrevious     := Screen.Cursor;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;

  try    
  // the task

  finally    
    Screen.Cursor := cPrevious;
  end;
end;
```

With FireMonkey, *Screen* doesn't have a property: *Cursor*.

What is the best way to give some feedback to the user?

---

---

I followed the comments and the answer... with a *TPanel* which has less opacity, and a *TAniIndicator* (I also blur the other components):

[image: Feedback]

Thank you!

Comment: Dimming the form (by overlaying some alpha-blended rectangle) and displaying an animated GIF - like one of those which can be generated at http://www.ajaxload.info/ - maybe?

Comment: Also if no user interaction is desired during this time, you could make it more obvious by disabling the controls and displaying a panel with a message like "Please wait while..." and the animated gif like mjn suggested, or a progress bar to indicate that the app is not frozen, etc.


@mjn: +1 for dimming effect and gif, nice touch

Comment: yes, that's make sense... FYI, I have used a TAniIndicator which is a component which looks like any ajaxload :o)

Comment: @Whiler: it looks like the UIActivityIndicator on the iPhone or the NSActivityIndicator on the Mac.

Comment: @Rudy: You have 2 default styles: aiLinear (in the screenshot) and aiCircular (which uses circles instead of the bar...)

Comment: When doing this in Delphi Classic, you should wrap your time-consuming action in a `try` block and set the screen cursor back in the `finally` section.  Otherwise an exception in the time-consuming activity leaves the cursor in the hour glass state.

Comment: I agree... the example is really simple... I update it...

Comment: @Whiler you should move the solution into it's own answer and mark it as the accepted solution instead of the answer you originally picked.

Comment: @Whiler. Thanks for the tip about blurring the background. In XE3 at least, all the child controls of say a TLayout or TPanel get disabled if you add and enable a TEffect...very useful. (Glow type effects don't disable the child controls however)

Comment: EDIT - Scrub that..Although buttons do not *appear* to be working when blurred or rippled, they still process onClick events.

Comment: @sergeantKK: The _panel_ I spoke above is **not** the _panel_ which contains the _children_ this is another one, `bring to front`... which is only visible when I display the feedback... as it is `bring to front` it's over the other components, and I don't need to manage their `enabled`properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mjn pointed out, the glass hour cursor is no more the only wait pattern you can utilize.

For example, in Silverlight/WPF, you can use a busy indicator control,
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightBusyIndicator.aspx

So you may try to do something similar inside FireMonkey. There may be a similar control for you to use already, or you can write your own.

**Update: [TAniIndicator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TAniIndicator) is the component to use**

Comment: Apparently, it isn't even a possible pattern any more (at least not out of the box)...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Do you mean `TAniIndicator` is no longer available in FireMonkey?

Answer (score 1):

FireMonkey TScreen has no Cursor property, but global Platform instance has a SetCursor method:

uses
  FMX.Platform, System.UITypes;

...
  Platform.SetCursor(nil, crHourGlass);
  try
   ...
  finally
    Platform.SetCursor(nil, crDefault);
  end;

Comment: I just try your script... It works as long as the script is not over, and you don't call `ProcessMessages`...   `Platform.SetCursor(nil, crHourGlass);

  Sleep(3000);

  Beep;

  while (not CheckBox1.IsChecked) do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

  ShowMessage('over');`

Comment: In which unit is the `Platform` variable declared?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on XE3, FireMonkey2 running on XP:

```
`Application.MainForm.Cursor:= crHourGlass;`
```

Comment: FYI: It doesn't exist in XE2.

Comment: Moreover, I'd like the Hourglass everywhere, on all components... not only on the `Form` without components.

Comment: Yes, this approach has one HUGE and showstopping drawback: it only changes the cursor when it is above the form, not above any child control of the form. Since a form typically is full of children, this isn't even nearly good enough.